# How to refresh a fragment tab after a menubar selection?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

When browsing between fragment tabs in my application, the tab that I am going back to is automatically refreshed from an obsolete, to a current view. I would like to also have my application refresh the current tab after making a selection in the menubar.

What is the best way to do this? TIA

Comment: Where do you have problems implementing that logic?

Comment: @Luksprog I've updated with code. Thanks.

Comment: In your code you add again a fragment which is already added to the layout. Why don't you simply get a reference to that fragment and then call a refresh method on it to update it?

Comment: ...I think that is what I am trying to do. Feel free to suggest an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're not doing that. Get a reference to the fragment with findFragmentByTag() and then call the method on it to update it. I've seen you changed the stacktrace, you have something null in the openTracklogDialog() method at line 400

Comment: Do you want to refresh fragment? If yes, then write `FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tr.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, yourFragmentInstance);
    tr.commit()`

Comment: @APURVA Thanks! Logcat output = 02-28 22:09:57.862    6560-6560/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:347)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:382)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:374)

Comment: @Luksprog ...getting "null point exception" in Logcat, as well as currentView == null per conditional. I've tried setting currentView by, "dataCapture currentFragment = (dataCapture)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.data_capture);" as well as "dataCapture currentFragment = (dataCapture)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dataCapture");" with no success either way...further suggestions??? Thanks you for your patience.

Comment: You're using a layout as an id...

Comment: dirty answer: `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, new dataCapture()`

Comment: I've tried many variations on that structure with no luck....trying to do a ".findFragmentByTag" , but may not be setting a TAG properly, hence getting back the NULL value. Thanks for your thoughts on this matter!

Comment: If this is all you're trying to do, I think the proper way to do it would be with a `Preference` and `onPreferenceChangeListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by using FragmentManager to replace the obsolete fragment with a new one.
Now able to make a selection of an ActiveView menu item that triggers an event, and have the active fragment replaced with a current one showing this per screenshot below.
 [image: Screenshot showing ON-OFF indicator]

Problems getting this together were mostly related to identifying the correct R.id.layout reference to use in the FragmentManager syntax. I've posted the relevant XML and java code in hopes that others may find it useful.

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
  **android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"**
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

dataCapture.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:tag="data_capture"
android:id="@+id/data_capture"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
tools:context=".dataCapture" >
...
 <TextView
    style="@style/colorSizeStylexml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="Tracklog: " />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewOff"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:text="OFF"
         android:background="#ff000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textViewOn"
         android:layout_width="40dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
         android:text="ON"
         android:background="#ff58ff2d"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
 ...
 </LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
static int iTrackLogFlag = 0; //if value = (0) Tracklog is off, if (1)  Tracklog is on
public dataCapture dataCapture;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    //put Actionbar in tab mode
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //set titles for tabs
    ActionBar.Tab dataCaptureTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("DataCapture");
    ActionBar.Tab dataEditTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("DataEdit");
    ...

     /*******************************************************************************************
     *  Create instances of each of the fragments. dataCapture is refreshed several times from
     *  fragmentManager (ActiveBar menutab for tracklog ON-OFF, and at closure of lookup table
     *  edit PopupWindows) hence the different format.
     *******************************************************************************************/
    //Fragment dataCaptureFragment = new dataCapture();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    dataCapture dataCapture = new dataCapture();
    fragmentTransaction.add(dataCapture,"data_capture");
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    Fragment dataEditFragment = new dataEdit();
    ...
    //attach those fragment instances to their respective tabs
    dataCaptureTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(dataCapture));
    dataEditTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(dataEditFragment));
    ...
    //add each tab to the ActionBar
    actionBar.addTab(dataCaptureTab);
    actionBar.addTab(dataEditTab);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null){//...do nothing
    }else if (savedInstanceState != null){
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX,0));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.corax, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem_tracklogOnOff:
            openTracklogDialog();//opens a dialog box...trying to minimize clutter in the toolbar.
            //
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private void openTracklogDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder TracklogDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TracklogDialog.setTitle("Tracklog control");
    TracklogDialog.setMessage("Press a button below to start or stop the tracklog.");
    TracklogDialog.setPositiveButton("STOP",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            iTrackLogFlag = 0;//"0" means OFF, sets button on frontend to black w/white letters OFF
        }
    });
    TracklogDialog.setNegativeButton("START",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tracklog started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            iTrackLogFlag = 1;//"1" means ON, sets button to green w/black letters

            Fragment currentFragment = (dataCapture)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("data_capture");
            if(currentFragment == null) {
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "This == NULL.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentFragment = new dataCapture();
            }else if(currentFragment != null){
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new dataCapture(),"data_capture").addToBackStack(null).commit();
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "This != NULL. currentFragment = "+currentFragment+", dataCapture = "+dataCapture+".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = TracklogDialog.create();
    alert.show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a update method in your fragment.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public void update(){
        //TODO: Do Update
    }
}
```

Make a method like this in your MainActivity. Call it when you need to refresh the fragment.

```
public void refreshData(){
    try {
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        fragment.update();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        //MyFragment not active, do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't the update method need to be static in order to be called from Activity? Are you also suggesting that .beginTransaction/.replace/.commit go into the update() method in the fragment class? Thanks.

Comment: No, and no. You're getting the fragment object from the `FragmentManager`. It should already have been instantiated when you display it. Since the fragment has access to its own views, it shouldn't need to go through the `FragmentManager` in order to update itself. This is the solution that @Luksprog has suggested.

Comment: Okay, so what is called by update() in the fragment class? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Only you can know that. For all intents and purposes, you have shared none of your code. There is no way for me or anyone else to know what your updating.

Comment: Thanks, I've shared more code in my question. Also I've added my implementation of your suggested answer above. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: If you get a null fragment, then `R.id.layout` is not populated with anything. How are you adding the fragment to your activity?

Comment: I should tell you that I am very close to being done with this question. No, that does not answer my question. The entire reason I asked was because you should always have a fragment showing in your activity, right? So, if you are adding that fragment into your fragment container, `R.id.layout`, then there is absolutely no reason that `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layout);` should return null.

Comment: Thank you for your time and assistance with this issue. You have helped a great deal. My sincere apologies if I have caused frustration.

Comment: You should look in to Preferences, it is a much better way of accomplishing this very simple task.